# bash: синхронизация скрипта с параллельно запущенными им дочерними процессами. Как / можно ли?

Tags: bash, асинхронность, процесс

**Вопрос по bash**

Хочу запустить неск. экземпляров приложения(ий) параллельно из сценария для bash. Нужно что-то вроде синхронизации.

Запускаю через & . При этом получается, что запускающий скрипт не знает о дальн. "судьбе" запущенного процесса. Например, хотелось бы, использовать:

1. **Ожидание.** После запуска всех нужных (параллельно запущенных) приложений, запустивший их скрипт ждал, пока все они не завершатся и/или какие-н. из них. После окончания, напр., скрипт м. выдать сообщения, что операция завершена.
2. **Прерывание.** Если из скрипта запущено много процессов, через диспетчер процессов неудобно их принудительно завершать (в случае, когда ждать надоедает). Если бы дочерний процесс был запущен последовательно (без &), то закрыв окно консоли, из которой был запущен скрипт, завершились (принудительно) и все порождённые им процессы. Хотелось бы получить что-то вроде того и для параллельно (через &) запущенных процессов. Напр., скрипт спрашивает, "завершить ли дочерние процессы?", ввожу что-л. в консоли и все параллельно запущенные процессы принудительно завершаются.

**ВОПРОС: как вообще по-нормальному (без изобретения велосипедов) это в bash можно сделать и вообще, можно ли?**

---

**По запросу @alexander-barakin - неработающий wait:**

### *Файл: inv_3.BASh*

```
#!/bin/bash

      declare Path="$(dirname "${0}")"; Path="${Path%/}/";
      declare Data="${Path}t2.data.fifo";
      declare Can_write="${Path}t2.can.fifo";


  trap "echo _ > \"${Can_write}\"; " Usr1;

  aValue=$BASHPID;
  bash "${Path}sub_3.BASh" $aValue &

  wait;

  echo ;
  echo "    JOBS:";
  jobs -pr;
  echo ;

  echo "Завершено."
```

---

### *Файл: sub_3.BASh*

```
#!/bin/bash

  declare theRecievers="${1}";

      declare Path="$(dirname "${0}")"; Path="${Path%/}/";
      declare Data="${Path}t2.data.fifo";
      declare Can_write="${Path}t2.can.fifo";

  trap "echo $BASHPID: END" Exit;

  kill -s Usr1 ${theRecievers};

  i=2;
  while ((i--)); do
    while ! read < "${Can_write}"; do
      kill -s Usr1 ${theRecievers}; 
    done;
  done;
```

---

*Воспроизведение:*

1. Создаёте файлы inv_3.BASh, sub_3.BASh
2. В том же каталоге создаёте pipe: t2.can.fifo, t2.data.fifo
3. В консоли: `bash "inv_3.BASh"; echo $?;`

Ожидаемое (от wait) поведение:

Сценарий, в котором вызывается wait не выполняет команды после wait, пока не завершится доч. процесс, т. е., вывода "... JOBS: ..." вообще не д. быть до завершения доч. процесса.

Вижу:

```
JOBS:
    14066
```

4. Открываю диспетчер процессов: процесс с pid 14066 есть.
   Значение pid, естеств., каждый раз - разное.

Answer (score 2):

1. ожидание завершения всех дочерних процессов осуществляется с помощью команды `wait`.
2. перехват сигнала `sigint` (который передаётся процессу при нажатии <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) и завершение всех дочерних процессов неплохо описано, например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/kill-background-process-when-shell-script-exit).

Comment: Заметил, что wait работает неправильно, если дочерний процесс находится в ожидании (ждёт записи в pipe) - т. е., запускающий процесс идёт выполняет команды после вызова wait, а дочерний ещё остаётся не завершённым.

Comment: @ChapaikinVA не слыхал о подобном. если вас не затруднит, приведите, пожалуйста, воспроизводимый пример этой «неправильности» (с пояснением: что ожидается и что имеется).

Comment: добавил пример.

Comment: а, понятно. вы передаёте процессу сигнал в то время, когда он ожидает завершения работы дочерних процессов. wait при получении сигнала сразу же прекращается. это описано в `man bash` («If bash is waiting…»). как с этим справиться — можно найти в поисковике по ключевым словам «bash trap wait». вот, например, первое попавшееся: http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html